# Dependency between two custom elements, and Polymer serve's paths

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-3.x

I've created 2 custom elements (let's call them element-a and element-b) with polymer 3.0.

Each of them individually works fine when I launch "polymer serve" from /my/path/to/element-a, then use a browser to access URL "http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/element-a/demo/" ... same thing if I launch "polymer serve" from /my/path/to/element-b, then access "http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/element-b/demo/"

Now I want "element-b" to be able to instanciate a "element-a" in some cases. That might sound easy, yet so far I haven't been able to do that.

First, the only way I found to serve both elements at the same time is to launch "polymer serve" from /my/path/to. Then I access my elements at "http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/polymer/element-a/demo/" or "http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/polymer/element-b/demo/". It works but I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing it (?)

Then, in element-b.js I tried to add an import to element-a like that :

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '../element-a/element-a.js';

class ElementB extends PolymerElement {
 ...
}

window.customElements.define('element-b', ElementB);
```

element-a.js stays unchanged :

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';

class ElementA extends PolymerElement {
 ...
}

window.customElements.define('element-a', ElementA);
```

Unfortunately, that does'n work : element-b doesn't show anymore, instead I get javascript errors in the console :

with firefox :

> NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported dom-module.js:182

with chrome :

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on  'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry
>       at http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/polymer/element-a/node_modules/@polymer/polymer/lib/elements/dom-module.js:175:16

I'm very confused about how to use polymer-serve, I don't understand how paths such as those in include statement get rewrited, and I can't find detailed documentation about these things besides introduction tutorials ...

Any help, explanations or useful links would be greatly appreciated !
Thanks,

Hervé

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`In component A`

```js
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';

class ElementA extends PolymerElement {
 static get template{
    return html `<p>This is sample test</p>`
 }
}

window.customElements.define('element-a', ElementA);
```

`In component-b`

```js
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import './element-a.js';

class ElementB extends PolymerElement {
  static get template{
    return html `<element-a></element-b>`
  }
}

window.customElements.define('element-b', ElementB);
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get another message : 
Failed to fetch http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/polymer/element-b/element-a.js

(element-a and element-b each have their own subfolders, as they are two different elements and element-a can be used without element-b)

Comment: Then change the path in import... `import {ElementA} from '../element-a-folder/element-a.js'` ...

Comment: Well, this is basically what I had before (except for the "{ElementA} from"). I tried it and unsuprisingly it takes me back to the first error.

Comment: Just put both files in same folder and replace import in element-b js file., And use this import `import {ElementA} from './element-a.js'` ...and check if loading fine., Then the path u trying to load is incorrect... Check folder structure properly

Comment: "Just put both files in same folder"
=> Yes, that works, but that's ugly ! These are two different elements, I want them to have their own folders and package.json, and be able to use only element-a in an application without element-b if I want to ...

"Then the path u trying to load is incorrect"
=> Incorrect compared to what ? 

"Check folder structure properly"
=> OK, but what should I check ? What should the structure look like ? Would you have any link to a documentation describing it ?

Thanks for your help.